# Creating a method which receives polymorphic input

Tags: java, methods, syntax-error, call, polymorphic-associations

I want to call a specific method named "center" which I use to print the centres of the objects as a string. I want this method to accept any object from these classes. The centres of the object are the first two int values (x,y). All of these classes share this method as it is inherited from the Circle2 class. I call this method (namely the center() method) in the main method of this class. The method I intend to create is supposed to output (replacing the println methods in the main) the values for centres of these objects (which I will eventually place within an ArrayList, whose process I'll have to review, as I can't recall by what means I would go about this). Any insight on either of these would be highly helpful.

In short--I mean to create a method in this class that will accept any of the objects constructed in this main (as they presently are) as input and then output the result of calling the center() method that they all have in common.

Apologies if my explanation isn't completely clear--if it isn't totally apparent what I mean to do, I would be happy to attempt to give further clarity on the issue.

```
public class TestPoly2
{
    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class TestPoly2
     */
    public TestPoly2()
    {

    }

    public String showCenter()
    {
        return "This method is supposed to output (replacing the println methods in the main) the values for centres of these objects (which I will eventually place within an ArrayList (whose process I'll have to review, as I can't recall by what means I would go about this) ";
    }

    public static void main(String []args)
    {
        Circle2 one =  new Circle2(5, 10, 4);
        Cylinder2 two = new Cylinder2(8, 7, 4, 12);
        Oval2 three =  new Oval2(3, 4, 9, 14);
        OvalCylinder2 four =  new OvalCylinder2(11, 14, 15, 10, 12);

        System.out.println(one.center());
        System.out.println(two.center());
        System.out.println(three.center());
        System.out.println(four.center());
    }
}
```

The method (center()) that I've been referencing is as follows:

```
public String center()
{
     return "center is at (" + x + "," + y + ")";
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to write a method that can take any of these classes as a parameter, or are you trying to write a method that each of the classes implement?

Comment: I am trying to write a method that can take an object stored in an ArrayList and use the object within the center() method in order to report back the output within that last black of code in the main method. Essentially to do the job of this code `System.out.println(one.center());`

Comment: In this article, [Inheritance of Java](http://java8.in/unit-2-prog-6-inheritance-in-java/), you can refer "Reason to use Inheritance" section...

Comment: Read through your posting--didn't see a solution in there, though I tried a couple things relative to the article, and they didn't pan out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the proper method to perform the task.

```
    public static void showCenter(Circle2 object)
    {
        System.out.println(object.center());
    }
```

For anyone who is curious, of course.
Thank you for the assistance, guys.

Answer (score 1):

u may try this:

```
public interface Shape {

    public String center();
}

public class Circle2 implements Shape {
    //ur rest of the code here...

    @Override
    public String center() {
      // return statement here.
    }
}
```

edit ur method like this:

```
public String showCenter(Shape shape) {
  return shape.center();
}
```

Comment: The solution you have provided here doesn't exactly coincide with the situation I set up. I desire to create a method in this class that will accept any of the objects constructed in this main, without any changes within the objects' classes. I just need to understand how to create a method which performs the task of printing the center() method's output by using a given object from an ArrayList of objects (which resemble the objects given in the main).